# Skip parts of the input in boost::spirit::qi if a function call comes back true

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I've been playing around with boost::spirit::qi lately and have been trying to write my own (very, very simple) scripting language which it will parse. I've had trouble when I've got to the if statements in the script. I need the parser to skip parts of the input if a function call comes back true.

For example, I have token defined as to accept variable names (a-zA-Z_) and comparison set to accept ">" or "<". An example of the code is below.

```
comparison_statement = token >> comparison >> token;
statement            = lit("if ") >> comparison_statement[&compare] >> "then";

qi::phrase_parse(first, last, script, space);  // This call the parser
```

How would I go about skipping the next section if the function compare comes back true?

Comment: This is exactly what the [epsilon parser](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/eps.html) is for; have you tried it?

Comment: No, I'm new to Boost and never seen this. I've looked at the documentation but it's a little bit confusing, could you give me an example of how to use it? Thanks :)

Comment: The "Semantic Predicate" paragraph _is_ the relevant example.

Comment: I feel sort of stupid for asking, but how can this be used to skip part of the input? I'm reading that as when the function returns false it raises a parse error. How can that be used as a conditional?

Comment: By having the `eps` branch on one side of an alternative (`|`), and something else (a noop maybe in your case) on the other side of the alternative.

Comment: Ohhhh, I get it now. I was (rather stupidly) reading it as if the fail would mean that the entire parse would fail, not just that test. Thankyou so much :)

Comment: No stupidity involved; no one would say that Spirit has no learning curve. :-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A conditional within the parser can be written by using the [Epsilon Parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/eps.html%20Epsilon%20Parser). This will call the function you supply to it and if that function returns false will fail that particular check and go on to the next or.

For example:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> rool;
rool = a | b | eps(f) | d
```